# Django and mariadb not working with istartswith correctly using german umlauts

Tags: django, mariadb

the following query should only return all cities starting with "Ö" (German umlaut).

```
letter = 'Ö'
City.objects.filter(name__istartswith=letter)
```

But it returns cities starting with O and Ö.

I use django 1.11 and mariadb. 
I allready set COLLATE on that table to utf8_bin but this haven't changed the behavior within django.

This is the simplified SQL query

```
SELECT `cities_city`.`name` FROM `cities_city` WHERE `cities_city`.`name` LIKE "Ö%";
```

and here the SHOW CREATE TABLE output:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `cities_city`
    -> ;
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table       | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| cities_city | CREATE TABLE `cities_city` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_std` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `location` point NOT NULL,
  `population` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `elevation` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kind` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `region_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subregion_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cities_city_country_id_2f07e352_uniq` (`country_id`,`region_id`,`subregion_id`,`id`,`name`),
  KEY `cities_city_b068931c` (`name`),
  KEY `cities_city_16c3f481` (`name_std`),
  KEY `cities_city_region_id_0227cdac_fk_cities_region_id` (`region_id`),
  KEY `cities_city_subregion_id_9fbab97d_fk_cities_subregion_id` (`subregion_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cities_city_country_id_779ae117_fk_cities_country_id` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `cities_country` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cities_city_region_id_0227cdac_fk_cities_region_id` FOREIGN KEY (`region_id`) REFERENCES `cities_region` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cities_city_subregion_id_9fbab97d_fk_cities_subregion_id` FOREIGN KEY (`subregion_id`) REFERENCES `cities_subregion` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11468436 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin |
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Let's see the `SELECT` and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- This is to rule out MySQL.  (Or point out why MySQL is at fault.)

Comment: Thx for the fast respond, do you need anything else to know?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a subtle one.

The clue is here:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE table_name = 'cities_city';
```

The explanation...

```
`name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
```

is `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` because that is the default collation for utf8.

This table *default*:

```
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11468436 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

gives `utf8_bin` to any *newly added rows*.

Perhaps you did the obvious `ALTER TABLE` to change to _bin?  Instead:

```
ALTER TABLE cities_city
    CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
               COLLATE       utf8_bin;
```

this will go into each string column and make the change.  Note that indexes (etc) must be rebuilt when the collation changes.

Comment: Thank you, I used phpmyadmin to change the collation of the table. I tried your SQL query, but I got this error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'utf8_bin' at line 1

Comment: I tried this and it worked: ALTER TABLE <table name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

Comment: (I fixed my syntax.)

Comment: I've seen your changes and already up-voted your answer. Thank you!